# what's the meaning of the master process creates the listen socket and sends it to interested workers in node?

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets

nodejs cluster api says :The second approach is where the master process creates the listen socket and sends it to interested workers. The workers then accept incoming connections directly.

I ' M fused about what is the listen socket  and how it can send to workers.moreever. what the relationship between the listen socket and the incomming connections.

Comment: What is the question in this? If you dont got something we can reliably answer on then we cant help you...

Comment: Did my answer help? It'd be appreciated if you set it as the accepted answer, or at least give some feedback!

Answer (score 0):

The listen socket is what Node (or any networked software) will use to map an external request or incoming data to the application code that you've written to handle it.

> The second approach is where the master process creates the listen
>   socket and sends it to interested workers. The workers then accept
>   incoming connections directly.

Means that the master script will create a port that can be shared transparently between the workers, allowing you to connect to port `3000`, for example, and have a bunch of workers deal with the incoming request.

See this diagram below. In this instance `Worker 2` ends up dealing with the request:

```
Request -> [localhost:3000] -> Worker 1  
                            -> Worker 2 -> Handle Request -> Send back result 
                            -> Worker 3
                            -> Worker 4
```

This allows you to write applications that are more fault tolerant and responsive, because if there's an issue in one of the workers, the master (if configured correctly) will send the request to a worker that isn't as busy or is operating normally.